# Get results from multiple tables from single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have one major problem i have mysql database with 18 different tables and i want to search in all those table by using fulltext search  how to do that without compromising the performance and also without any frameworks only bt using php and mysql thanks in advance

Comment: Fulltext search on 18 tables?  That's almost the definition of compromised performance.

Comment: or please give me another better option for searching thanks

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve doing a fulltext search on entire database. Maybe creating a stored procedure might help?

Comment: i am making a searching page that can search in all 18 tables

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, MySQL can't make a fulltext (or any type of search) index across multiple tables.

if the tables are completely different you won't be able to carry out any form of JOINS, and therefore you won't be able to perform 1 full text search for 18 tables.

Comment: Ok then please help me how can i make a search page from 18 diiferent tables

Comment: The only suggestion I'd say would be to create a aggregate table? This won't be easy to do though, and very time consuming, if you are unsure what it is, look it up on google

Answer (score 0):

```
$tables = array('table1','table2','table3','table4','table5');
$return = array();
foreach( $tables as $table) ){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE field LIKE ?";
    $pdo = new PDO($connection_params); // Your PDO connection
    $stm = $pdo->prepare($query); // Prepare query
    $stm->execute(array('%'.$search_string.'%')); // Look for where field LIKE $search_string
    while($result = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ){
        $return[$table][] = $result;
    }
}
```

You could also do like this, if there is a different field to look for in each table as well.

```
$tables = array('table1'=>'field1','table2'=>'field2','table3'=>'field3','table4'=>'field4','table5'=>'field5');
$return = array();
foreach( $tables as $table => $field) ){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$field." LIKE ?";
    $pdo = new PDO($connection_params); // Your PDO connection
    $stm = $pdo->prepare($query); // Prepare query
    $stm->execute(array('%'.$search_string.'%')); // Look for where field LIKE $search_string
    while($result = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ){
        $return[$table][] = $result;
    }
}
```

You will get an array that looks something like this:

```
array(
    'table1' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'val',
            'field1'=> 'val',
            'field2'=> 'val
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'val',
            'field1'=> 'val',
            'field2'=> 'val
        )
    ),
    'table2' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'val',
            'field1'=> 'val',
            'field2'=> 'val
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'val',
            'field1'=> 'val',
            'field2'=> 'val
        )
    ) ........ all tables and all rows with field LIKE %yoursearchvalue%
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create one query to search all 18 tables.

You should create a stored procedure in mySQL to do whatever you want - search through each table separately putting results into temp table for example and the return this results in any format you like. Then just call that stored procedure from PHP code.